# playframework form inputs with array names

Tags: java, arrays, templates, input, playframework

I'm trying to submit a form with a few textareas like this:

```
<textarea name="criticism[]" rows="3" cols="5"></textarea>
```

The textarea needs to have an array as the name because there can be an unlimited number of them on the page, added by the user with js.

The values are passed to the controller correctly.

In the controller I do `params.flash()` which seems to add the values to the seession, since if I do `${flash}` in the template they are printed to the screen. However, I can't access them in any way.  `${flash.criticism}` returns null, and `${flash.criticism[x]}` will return an out of bounds error.

Am I missing anything syntax wise?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash scope is only available to the current request and the next one. To put something in the session use session.

However flash and session are not intended to store values. They are cookie limited to 4kb. To store something use the db and/or the cache

If you want to re-render your values in the next page, just pass the string array as a `'criticism'` parameter to the next render method and use it in your template with `${criticism[x]}`